# Database update outside application

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

am I correct assuming that if a different process updates the DB then my NHibernate powered application will be out-of-sync? I'm almost using non-lazy update.

My target DB is mysql 5.0, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles that "Easy one on NHibernate"; the tags should show that it's for NHibernate (which you've done) and the title should hint at the topic to help out both Googlers looking for a similar answer and people in here to spot it's a question they might be able to answer.

Comment: At the time I wrote, nothing better came to my mind. Hope this one is more suited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to answer that without more context.

What type of application are you thinking about (web, desktop, other)?

What do you think would be out of sync exactly?

If you have a desktop application with an open window with an open session that has data loaded and you change the same entities somewhere else, of course the DB will be out of sync, but you can use Refresh to update those entities.

If you use NH second-level caching and you modify the cached entities somewhere else, the cache contents will be out of sync, but you can still use Refresh or cache-controlling methods to update directly from the DB.

In all cases, NH provides support for optimistic concurrency by using Version properties; those prevent modifications to out-of-sync entities.

Comment: I'm developing an application that will run 24/7. My PM would like to be able to change some application parameters without having to restart it, and almost every parameter is in the DB. If I change the DB using - for example - mysql CLI utility, NHibernate won't be able to detect the update. I just wanted to be sure of that

Comment: Again: what type of application? NH can't detect changes automatically any less or any more than any other data access library. You can poll the db periodically if you want, and you'll get updated data.

Comment: sorry, it will be a desktop application (or a service maybe).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the objects in your current session will be out of sync, the same way a DataSet/DataTable would be out of sync if you fetch it and another process updates the same data.